# Accessing nested JSON keys with multiple colons in row

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON object that I don't know how to access - the console only ever prints `undefined`.

I don't know how to access multiple keys with colons.

The JSON object:

```
 {
  'soapenv:Envelope': {
    '$': {
      'xmlns:soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
      'xmlns:soapenc': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
      'xmlns:xsd': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
      'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    },
    'soapenv:Header': [
      ''
    ],
    'soapenv:Body': [
      {
        'ns5:loginResponse': [
          {
            '$': {
              'xmlns:ns5': ' /* Website sending me this response */ '
            },
            'ns5:id': [
              /*Sessionkey*/
            ],
            'ns5:rc': [
              '0'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I have already tried:

```
console.dir(res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0][0]['ns5:rc'])

console.dir(res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["ns5:loginResponse"])["ns5:rc"]
```

... and a bunch of others I don't know anymore.

Comment: I think you're missing a `['$']` before `['ns5:rc']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it one step at the time. The presence of the colons shouldn't affect anything, the keys are just strings. Start with seeing what `res["soapenv:Envelope"]` gets you. For me, in the console, i can access it just fine.

I tried res
`["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0]["ns5:loginResponse"][0]["ns5:rc"]` and that also worked.

If you can't access the object and its the return from a request, its very possible your router has special methods on res that you're supposed to use to access it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Take it stepwise, looking at the output at each stage

Beware that there is a mixture of arrays and objects, which is where you are having difficulties. Where the output starts with the `{`, it is an object, so the next thing to append to your entry should be a property name. In contrast, when the output starts with `[`, it is an array, so the next thing to append should be a number such as [0] to obtain the first element.

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]
```

{$: {…}, soapenv:Header: Array(1), soapenv:Body: Array(1)}

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]
```

[{…}]

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0]
```

{ns5:loginResponse: Array(1)}

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0]["ns5:loginResponse"]
```

[{…}]

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0]["ns5:loginResponse"][0]
```

{$: {…}, ns5:id: Array(0), ns5:rc: Array(1)}

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0]["ns5:loginResponse"][0]["$"]
```

{xmlns:ns5: " /* Website sending me this response */ "}

```
res["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"][0]["ns5:loginResponse"][0]["$"]["xmlns:ns5"]
```

" /* Website sending me this response */ "

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help if you ran your JSON through a prettifier to make it more readable.

The colons won't mean anything because they're part of a string.

Here's what you need to get to `ns5:rc`

```
res['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['ns5:loginResponse'][0]['ns5:rc']
```